# Hyperledger Fabric: Development environment setup make dist-clean allfailing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am getting the following error while setting up the development environment for fabric2.3.

go version go1.17.1 linux/amd64

setup environment: Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine

CLI output after running 'make dist-clean all'

```
Testing with pkcs11...
Trying configuration [0]
--- FAIL: TestGetBCCSPFromOpts (0.00s)
pkcs11_test.go:67:
Error Trace: pkcs11_test.go:67
Error: Received unexpected error:
pkcs11: library path not provided
Could not initialize BCCSP PKCS11
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/factory.GetBCCSPFromOpts
/home/souptik/github.com/souptikmakarov/fabric/bccsp/factory/pkcs11.go:93
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/factory.TestGetBCCSPFromOpts
/home/souptik/github.com/souptikmakarov/fabric/bccsp/factory/pkcs11_test.go:57
testing.tRunner
/usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1193
runtime.goexit
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371
Test: TestGetBCCSPFromOpts
--- FAIL: TestPKCS11FactoryGet (0.00s)
pkcs11factory_test.go:48:
Error Trace: pkcs11factory_test.go:48
Error: Received unexpected error:
pkcs11: library path not provided
Test: TestPKCS11FactoryGet
--- FAIL: TestPKCS11FactoryGetEmptyKeyStorePath (0.00s)
pkcs11factory_test.go:66:
Error Trace: pkcs11factory_test.go:66
Error: Received unexpected error:
pkcs11: library path not provided
Test: TestPKCS11FactoryGetEmptyKeyStorePath
FAIL
```

I have even tried installing pkcs11-proxy from https://github.com/SUNET/pkcs11-proxy but that didn't solve the issue
Any help is appreciated in fixing this

Comment: Did you install softhsm as per the pre-reqs described here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/dev-setup/devenv.html ?

Comment: Yes. It says for MAC to set the following variables
export PKCS11_LIB="/usr/local/Cellar/softhsm/2.6.1/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so"
export PKCS11_PIN=98765432
export PKCS11_LABEL="ForFabric"
What should I set for Ubuntu?

Comment: try
export PKCS11_LIB="/usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so"
export PKCS11_PIN=98765432
export PKCS11_LABEL="ForFabric"

Comment: This worked thank you. Shouldn't this be included in the documentation just after the softhsm setup step

Comment: The tests should be able to find the library if it's in a couple of possible locations but sounds like it isn't, however the location of the softhsm2 library can be dependent on how you install it (as well as the platform you are using). The docs do provide a possible mac example but it's upto the developer to understand how softhsm2 was installed and where it put's the library as to use PKCS11 you do need to know where the library is on the file system. I guess whoever wrote the docs was a Mac user. There is an issue open to address that page so maybe adding an ubuntu example could be done